# Creating fixed document causes memory leak

Tags: c#, wpf, memory-leaks, fixeddocument

I'm creating WPF report in my application and I've found out, that each time I create report, the report stays in the memory. I completely wiped out the document content and I'm printing only a single empty UserControl. I reduced the code to the minimum, but it is still leaking. Do you have any idea what I'm doing wrong - or what I'm not doing?

Profiling shows that the problem is that the ContextLayoutManager keeps reference on FixedPage in ContextLayoutManager.LayoutQueue.Request

```
    private AutoResetEvent _documentGenerated = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    private Stream _outputStream;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        using (_outputStream = new FileStream(@"c:\report_tst.xps", FileMode.Create))
        {
            Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(doWork));
            thread.Name = "Report generating thread";
            thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            thread.Start();

            _documentGenerated.WaitOne();
        }
    }

    private void doWork()
    {
        FixedDocument fixedDoc = new FixedDocument();
        PageContent pageContent = new PageContent();
        FixedPage fixedPage = new FixedPage();
        fixedPage.Children.Add(new UserControl());
        ((IAddChild)pageContent).AddChild(fixedPage);
        fixedDoc.Pages.Add(pageContent);

        var package = Package.Open(_outputStream, FileMode.Create);
        var xpsDoc = new XpsDocument(package, CompressionOption.Normal);
        XpsDocumentWriter xpsWriter = XpsDocument.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(xpsDoc);

        xpsWriter.Write(((IDocumentPaginatorSource)fixedDoc).DocumentPaginator);

        xpsDoc.Close();
        package.Close();

        _documentGenerated.Set();
    }
```

Thanks for any advise.